# New GWT maven plugin

Tags: maven, gwt, maven-plugin

I'm getting the error below when when I try to compile.
The goal is gwt:compile
I do set the moduleName as a variable. 
The module name is `com.example.app.App`

Same thing command line `~/work/projects/gwt/app$ mvn gwt:compile "-DmoduleName=com.example.app.App"`

> Failed to execute goal
>   net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6:compile (default-cli) on
>   project mysandbox: The parameters 'moduleName' for goal
>   net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6:compile are missing or
>   invalid -> [Help 1]

On the other hand `mvn package` worked.

Here's my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <mavenVersion>3.0</mavenVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir</launcherDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- Do not upgrade past 3.1 to avoid triggering https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSOURCES-95 -->
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.3.14.v20161028</version>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-rc-6</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>app-client</module>
    <module>app-shared</module>
    <module>app-server</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your POM? (BTW, why do you want to only `gwt:compile`? which would not e.g. process your resources, run your annotation processors and add the generated sources directory as a source root)

Comment: I thought that I had to gwt:compile and then gwt:package-app,here's the pom.

Comment: If you want to package your project, then `mvn package` and that's it. If you'd like to "call" any "task" and have all other required "tasks" executed automatically, then I'm afraid Maven (and its linear build lifecycle) is not the appropriate tool (have a look at Gradle rather).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have a multi-module Maven project. Invoking `mvn gwt:compile` will try to execute that "goal" on each of the 4 modules (root module and 3 submodules). Because your `moduleName` property (used to configure the `moduleName` property of the `gwt:compile` goal) likely only exists in the `app-client` submodule, `gwt:compile` fails when applied to the root module or the `app-shared` submodule.

If you want to build your project, run `mvn package` (and if you don't want to run tests, pass `-DskipTests`).

Technically, you could also run `mvn gwt:compile`, but directly inside the submodule. For that to work, you'd first have to `mvn install` the `app-shared` submodule; otherwise Maven won't be able to resolve the dependency (as you would no longer be executing the full "reactor build".
For many reasons (see http://blog.lexspoon.org/2012/12/recursive-maven-considered-harmful.html and http://blog.ltgt.net/maven-is-broken-by-design/ as starting points), I highly discourage this practice (`mvn install` is an anti-pattern; most of the time what you want is actually `mvn verify`); and I also discourage using any phase before `package` with multi-module builds (which boils down to only ever using `mvn package`, possibly with `-DskipTests`, and `mvn verify`)